Getting error in server component in Next js v14+
// actions.ts
export async function getData() {
  try {
    const res = await fetch("https://api.example.com/data");
    if (!res.ok) {
      throw new Error("Failed to fetch data");
    }
    const data = await res.json();

    return data;
   catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
}

// Component.tsx
export default async function ExampleServerComponent() {
  const data = await getData("https://api.example.com/data");
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Data fetched on the server:</h1>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
}

This code throws an error:

An error occurred in the Server Components render. The specific message is omitted in production builds to avoid leaking sensitive details. A digest property is included on this error instance which may provide additional details about the nature of the error.

Not sure why this is throwing an error. I checked on local it's working fine but not working after I deployed my code on the server.
Later I converted server component to client component and it resolved the issue but that's not the best approach.

Your code has a syntax error. The try catch in the example is missing an } after return data. Is your actual code also missing that?

In addition to the missing curly braces mentioned by @Mads Hougesen in the comments, you should add "use server" directive at the top of your action.ts file to mark all exports of that file as Server Actions.
In NextJs Docs - Server Actions and Mutations:

A Server Action can be defined with the React "use server" directive. You can place the directive at the top of an async function to mark the function as a Server Action, or at the top of a separate file to mark all exports of that file as Server Actions.

actions.ts
"use server";
export async function getData() {
  try {
    const res = await fetch("https://api.example.com/data");
    if (!res.ok) {
      throw new Error("Failed to fetch data");
    }
    const data = await res.json();

    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
}

